# CollectionsFS files won't upload to the Meteor server

Tags: javascript, mongodb, file-upload, meteor

I'm fairly new to collectionFS so I'm probably wrong somewhere. I try to use collectionFS on a mobile device. Recording audio and uploading it to a server. I followed the doc and it seems to work except the files won't show up in the defined upload-directory on the server. They are visible in the mongoDB though.

```
Images = new FS.Collection('images', {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem('images', {path: '~/uploads/'})]
});
```

.

```
Template.main.events ({
        'click #record': function (){
          Meteor.startup(function () {
              // capture callback
              var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
                  var i, path, len;
                  for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                      path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
                      // do something interesting with the file
                      upload(mediaFiles[i]);
                  }
              };

              // capture error callback
              var captureError = function(error) {
                  navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
              };

              // start audio capture
              navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError);
          });

          function upload (file){
            Images.insert(file, function(err, fileObj){
              if (err) { console.Error(err);}
              else { console.log('done');}
            });
          }
        }
      })
```

Comment: Did you see the documentation?

Comment: I did. Perhaps I missed something?